# Must Declare Scalar Variable Exception

Tags: sql, c#-4.0

I'm using:

```
string insertQ = "insert into Customer(Name, CNIC, Address, Balance) values(@name, @cnic, @address, @balance); SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int);";

SqlCommand insertCmd1 = new SqlCommand(insertQ, con);

Int32 newId = (Int32)insertCmd1.ExecuteScalar();
```

but

> "Must Declare Scalar Variable"

exception is coming at `ExecuteScalar`.

Please tell me how to resolve it...

Comment: Is SQL Server meant to guess @name?

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass in values of your parameters:

```
string insertQ = "insert into Customer(Name, CNIC, Address, Balance) values(@name, @cnic, @address, @balance); SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int);";

SqlCommand insertCmd1 = new SqlCommand(insertQ, con); 
insertCmd.Parameters.Add("name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "name";     
insertCmd.Parameters.Add("cnic", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "cnic"; 
insertCmd.Parameters.Add("address", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "address";     
insertCmd.Parameters.Add("balance", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "balance"; 


Int32 newId = (Int32)insertCmd1.ExecuteScalar();
```

The `SqlDbType`s must match your scheme.

Comment: Use AddWithValue and also the SqlDbType is usually redundant.